# ViewPart activation broken with jre7 and SWT_AWT

Tags: eclipse-rcp, java-7, swt-awt

I am using the SWT_AWT bridge in my RCP application with jre6 and it works just fine. The setup code is taken from the [Eclipse Corner Article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Swing-SWT-Integration/index.html):

```
Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.EMBEDDED | SWT.NO_BACKGROUND);
Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame(composite);
JApplet applet = new JApplet();          
frame.add(applet);
return applet;
```

Now, when I switch to jre7, the view part that contains the bridge gets no longer activated through mouse events.

The issue appears at least on Win7, I haven't tried on other O/S yet.

Any ideas?

Comment: Filed at: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=377104